# How to find drivers and tools for eeePc F201e

Tags: drivers, eeepc

I got a F201e with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS preinstalled. I installed 12.10 but I can't get the ethernet and some of the function keys to work (e.g. adjust screen brightness)

The Asus website does not provide any drivers for ubuntu. Where/How could I find those?

Answer (score 2):

I found some answers at http://bach-online.de/2012/12/27/ubuntu-12-10-on-the-asus-f201e-x201e/

> Minor tweaks necessary For a few issues, some tweaks were necessary to
>   fix them.
>
> Brightness keys After the installation, the keys for the brightness
>   were not working. This could be fixed by editing the /etc/default/grub
>   file and changing the line "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
>   to "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=". After running
>   "sudo update-grub" in the terminal and rebooting, the keys were
>   working again.
>
> Network card not working Besides, the ethernet controller was not
>   recognized and did not work, while Wifi was functioning just fine.
>   This could be fixed my installing the package
>   linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic. This package will
>   install several other packages (depending on the current kernel used)
>   and after running "modprobe alx" in the terminal as super user, the
>   ethernet card was working also.